# Matplotlib figure not updating properly after updating axes

Tags: matplotlib

I have this following code snippet

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
output = np.transpose(np.loadtxt(f'./output00000.dat',dtype=float))
x = output[0,:]
y1 = output[1,:]
line, = ax.plot([1],[1],'k-')
line.set_data(x,y1)
```

If I try fig.canvas.draw() to update, the figure still only shows 1 data point. I can call `fig.axes[0].get_lines()[0].get_data()` to check that the Line object inside the axes has the updated data, but it doesn't show up in the figure.

If I initialize the line object with blank list, e.g., `ax.plot([],[],'k-')`, then the updated data does show up in the figure. I don't understand this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the data points of existing artists (the line plot in your example), the axes limits are not updated automatically. So the axes view is still focused on that one original data point `[1], [1]`<sup>(1)</sup>. You can adjust the axes limits via [`ax.relim()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.relim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.relim) so all data points will be visible in the plot.

---

<sub>(1) Regarding `ax.plot([],[],'k-')`, this should focus the view around the origin `(0, 0)`, so if your data happens to be scattered around there, it showed up for that reason.</sub>